# How to let Git know that certain files in the single branch are branched from each other

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge, git-branch

We have a product with different themes, that are stored in master branch like this

```
themes/theme_one/...
themes/theme_two/...
etc
```

Each folder has its own structure and keeps CSS and HTML files. Sometimes one of our customers wants to have a custom theme. Since we have a wide variety of themes, there is usually one that is highly similar to what customer needs and which requires cosmetic changes only. So what I usually do is create a branch new_customer, switch to that branch, copy the theme of choice (e.g. themes/theme_two/ -> themes/custom_theme/) and modify it, applying the changes the customer needs. Sometimes the changes are minimal, sometimes they are larger but the resultant theme still heavily inherits from its parent.

What is the most efficient way to organize that? Suppose we've noticed some random bugs in themes/theme_two/ and applied the fixes. Is theme some way to tell Git that themes/custom_theme/ is in reality something like a branch from themes/theme_two/ and all the changes should be reapplied there as well (even though they still exist in the context of their respective branches - master and new_customer).

Some time ago I was reading a book on Git and I vaguely remember something about submodules. Is it the classical way to solve such a problem and if yes, how will it work? Will I do something like this - set up a separate repo for themes (may be a branch for each theme) and then in main product master create themes/.../ folders and link them to respective theme branches. Then when I'll need to create a custom theme, I'll create a some_customer branch from main products's master, create a branch from the other repo's theme_two branch and load it as a submodule into themes/custom_theme/ of the new_customer branch?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the best way would be to do branch per theme and always merge from theme_two into custom_theme.  There is no way I know of to merge part of a git directory hierarchy -- and no way to record such a partial merge.